# Copying a cell value based on a checkbox checked

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the code I'm using to copy data from a form on the travelrequest sheet to travellog sheet:

```
    Sub Submit()

         Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
         refTable = Array("B = L5", "C = C5", "D=G5", "E=C10", "F=C9", "G=I9", "H=I10",      "I=C13", "J=C14", "K=C15", "L=C16", "M=C17", "N=C18", "O=I13", "P=I14", "Q=I15", "R=I16", "S=I17", "W=H20")

 Dim Row As Long
    Row = Worksheets("TravelLog").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    For Each trans In refTable
        Dim Dest As String, Field As String
        Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
        Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
        Worksheets("TravelLog").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("TravelRequest").Range(Field).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Now I have 3 cells that say YES and 3 cells that say NO and each cell has a activeX checkbox next to it.

When the user fills out the form I would like to be able to copy over the checkbox result too, so if the user selected YES,NO,YES then I want those to go into 3 separate cells on the next sheet.

So just like the above code it will need to be copied into a new row with its information.

NEW UPDATED CODE WORKS GOOD!

```
Sub Submit()

Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("B = L5", "C = C5", "D=G5", "E=C10", "F=C9", "G=I9", "H=I10", "I=C13", "J=C14", "K=C15", "L=C16", "M=C17", "N=C18", "O=I13", "P=I14", "Q=I15", "R=I16", "S=I17", "W=H20")
Dim Row As Long
Row = Worksheets("TravelLog").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

For Each trans In refTable
    Dim Dest As String, Field As String
    Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
    Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("TravelRequest").Range(Field).Value
Next

If Worksheets("TravelRequest").CheckBox1.Value Then
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("T" & Row).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("T" & Row).Value = "No"
End If

If Worksheets("TravelRequest").CheckBox2.Value Then
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("U" & Row).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("U" & Row).Value = "No"
End If

If Worksheets("TravelRequest").CheckBox3.Value Then
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("V" & Row).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("V" & Row).Value = "No"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't really need to post the modified code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each checkbox will automatically be named `CheckBox#` where `#` is the number in which in which it was created. If you turn on **Design Mode** in the Developer tab, and click on the check box. It will tell you the name of the check box to the left of the formula bar. You can also change the name here.

[image: Excel screenshot]

After that, you can determine if it's checked or not by doing this immediately before, or after the `For` loop.

```
Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("T" & Row).Value = Worksheets("TravelRequest").DrewsCheckBox.Value
```

If it's checked, the cell in column `T` will say `True`, if it's not checked it will say `False`. If you want it say something other than `True` or `False` on the TravelLog sheet, then you can do this

```
If Worksheets("TravelRequest").DrewsCheckBox.Value Then
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("T" & Row).Value = "Yes"
Else
    Worksheets("TravelLog").Range("T" & Row).Value = "No"
End If
```

Comment: So I would need to create 3 of these codes if I had 3 checkboxes?

Comment: @user3438974 Yes, replacing `T` with the column you want it to go to, and `DrewsCheckBox` with the name of the check box you want to compare.

Comment: I put your code in before and after the FOR statement and in both tries it says object required - debug If CheckBox1.Value Then

Comment: Try `If Worksheets("TravelRequest").CheckBox1.Value Then` instead.

Comment: Yes that worked! I updated my code above so people can use it.